# Add signed APT repo using Puppet

Tags: ubuntu, devops, puppet, apt

I want to install Telegraf using Puppet 6, and I'm finding it really difficult to do so by using the `apt` module. I'm using the module so I can import the GPG key and add the corresponding source.

My manifest looks something like this:

```rb
  include apt
 
  apt::key { 'influxdata':
    id     => '05CE15085FC09D18E99EFB22684A14CF2582E0C5',
    ensure => 'present',
    source => 'https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key',
  }
 
  apt::source { 'influxdata':
    comment  => 'InfluxData repo to download Telegraf agent.',
    location => 'https://repos.influxdata.com/debian',
    release  => 'stable',
    repos    => 'main',
    key      => {
      'id'     => '05CE15085FC09D18E99EFB22684A14CF2582E0C5',
      'source' => 'https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key',
    },
  } ~> exec { "apt-update":
    command =>  "/usr/bin/apt-get update"
  }
 
  package { 'telegraf':
    ensure  => 'latest',
  }
```

It seems to be working with no errors, but a quick `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdata.list` shows that the repo is missing the *signed-by* part:

```bash
# This file is managed by Puppet. DO NOT EDIT.
# InfluxData repo to download Telegraf agent.
deb [   ] https://repos.influxdata.com/debian stable main
```

**Ideally**, it should be:

```bash
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdb.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/debian stable main
```

What am I missing?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

You are probably missing at least that your repository works (do check), which will confirm that the needed key is in fact installed.

You may be missing that the `signed-by` option is not needed or intended for marking or using a signed repository.  Instead, it is for designating specific key(ring)s to use to verify the repository, as opposed to allowing *any* of the configured keys to be used.

You appear to be missing that, perhaps unintuitively, `apt::source::key` is merely a shortcut for declaring an `apt::key` resource (so yours is redundant with the explicitly declared `apt::key`).  That makes the key available for verifying that repository and others, but it does not limit the repository to being verified via that particular key.

You are surely missing the `apt::source::keyring` parameter, [whose docs](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/apt/reference#keyring) specify that it sets the `signed-by` option on the source.